# How does Christianity view gaslighting?

Tags: catholicism, abusive-relationships

[Gaslighting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting) since the advent of social media has become a political topic especially in todays world of organised disinformation and alt-truth.

How does Christianity view this? Has there been any papal encyclical directly confronting this? Or if not, can something be said from encyclicals that indirectly touch upon it.

Comment: When I was a child, a man walked along the cobbled road at dusk, using a long pole to open the glass side of the street gas-lights, and then to light them. A most useful service! But although I'm old, I'm not so old that I would have known about the 1930s fictions used to now hijack the phrase to apply to psychological 'warfare'. Thank-you to all who provided the links that cleared up my confusion. The Got Questions one was particularly helpful.

Comment: @Anne It's actually derived from a [1940s film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslight_(1944_film)).

Answer (score 8):

Gaslighting is widely recognised by Christians as a technique of emotional abuse:

- [What Is Gaslighting? Understanding the Warning Signs and Way of Escape - christianity.com](https://www.christianity.com/wiki/christian-life/what-is-gaslighting.html)
- [What is gaslighting? - gotquestions.org](https://www.gotquestions.org/gaslighting.html)
- [How to know if you're in an emotional abusive relationship - Focus on the Family](https://www.focusonthefamily.com/marriage/how-to-know-if-youre-in-an-emotionally-abusive-relationship/)
- [How to Think Straight When the Gaslighter Is Gaslighting You - Biblical Counseling Coalition](https://www.biblicalcounselingcoalition.org/2022/01/24/how-to-think-straight-when-the-gaslighter-is-gaslighting-you/)
- [Gaslighting in Relationships: Recognizing and Responding to Extreme Emotional Abuse - Tacoma Christian Counseling](https://tacomachristiancounseling.com/articles/gaslighting-in-relationships-recognizing-and-responding-to-extreme-emotional-abuse)

It's also been observed that theological gaslighting is a form of spiritual abuse:

- [Theological Gaslighting as Spiritual Abuse - Christianity Today](https://www.christianitytoday.com/scot-mcknight/2020/december/theological-gaslighting-as-spiritual-abuse.html)
- [Gaslighting in a world of Spiritual Abuse - Eternity News](https://www.eternitynews.com.au/australia/gaslighting-in-a-world-of-submission/)

I haven't been able to find much about what the Catholic Church specifically says about gaslighting - most of the Google results are instead about abusers within the Catholic Church who have gaslit others (accusations that are no doubt warranted in many cases.) While there are hypocrites and abusers in all denominations, there are also many people truly seeking to follow God and help others. There are many Catholic Counselling services around the world with licensed counsellors who would be able to help a victim of gaslighting. [Here's one example](https://dev.nwcounseling.org/domestic-violence-in-a-pandemic/) from a counselling centre which briefly mentions gaslighting.

Comment: Given that gaslighting is a form of lying, I can't see any room for divine tolerance of it, and any church that says otherwise has wandered far away from the truth.